# Marklogic errorlog truncating messages

Tags: debugging, error-logging, marklogic

Odd question.

Marklogic will truncate messages in the error log like so:

```
2012-09-19 10:36:12.130 Notice: _app_test_preview_8000: $finalPath = "/opt/bc/content/binary-content/article/test-single..."
```

by using the ellipses (...) and not show me the whole value.

Is there some way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

MarkLogic is using xdmp:describe internally to log information to ErrorLog.txt when it is logging value information. This is to prevent entire and very lengthy values to be logged into this log, and grow way faster than is practical.

Use xdmp:log explicitly on variables you want to debug, or use one of the debugging XQuery editors. I believe Oxygen, and XQDT do a good job, and there is also XQDebug..

HTH!

Comment: Yeah, I usually use xdmp:trace or xdmp:log, I was just wondering if I could be any lazier.

Comment: For XML variables that you are logging yourself try xdmp:quote() for displaying the whole thing without any truncating.

Answer (score 1):

Something I've grown accustomed to doing is this:

```
xdmp:log(fn:concat("The $var is: ", xdmp:describe($var)))
```

And when you see the ellipsis you can still use xdmp:describe(). Taken from the documentation [here](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp%3adescribe):

```
(: configure these as needed :)
let $max_sequence_length := 5
let $max_item_length := 5

xdmp:log(fn:concat("The $var is: ", 
  xdmp:describe(
    $var,
    $max_sequence_length, (: [$maxSequenceLength as xs:unsignedInt?] :)
    $max_item_length      (: [$maxItemLength as xs:unsignedInt*] :)
  )))
```